# McDonald's drive thru

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

How do you say " I am going to the McDonald's drive thru " in German?

> Mein Versuch : Ich fahre zu McD. Drive-thru?

Comment: My suggestion would be not to do this at all. I mean eating at the drive-thru ;-)

Comment: Ich bin doch zu faul, um zu Hause zu kochen. ;)

Comment: Selbst dann nehme ich nicht den Drive-In, sondern setze mich an einen Tisch. Im Auto einen Burger zu essen kommt meistens nicht so gut raus.

Comment: To sound German, just say "drive sru"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

McDonald's Drive Thru is actually called [**McDrive**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald%E2%80%99s#McDrive) in Germany. So you could safely say that.

Answer (score 8):

Like always there are possibilities that are used in colloquial language and some that are also correct but not used very frequently.

> Ich fahre zum McDonald’s-Drive-In.

This would be the version I consider to be used most of the times.

Or

> Ich fahre durch den McDondald’s-Drive-In.

To me this is possible but I consider it not to be used as often as the upper version.

In German, a drive thru is called *Drive-In* most of the times.

Comment: As pointed out by Thorsten Dittmar: The Drive through is called McDrive here, so you could as well colloquially say "Ich fahre zu McD, durch den McDrive".
Although it sounds a bit like you were trying to get to McD by driving through the McDrive, everyone will know what you mean and I doubt you'd talk about McD in a setting that doesn't allow coll. speak.